# sfmath: bug or feature? Tildes are wrongly displayed

Tags: fonts, math-mode, sans-serif, tilde, latin-modern

If I compile the following code (TeXLive 2011; Mac OS X 10.7.2, latexmk 4.26), I get wrongly placed tildes (in the middle of the letters instead of on top of them). Is this a bug?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[lm,T1experimental]{sfmath}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\begin{document}
    $\tilde{\psi}$ $\tilde{A}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Removing `\usepackage{lmodern}` and the `lm` package option from [`sfmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sfmath) seems to solve the problem. Note the package **[Bugs and Limitations](http://dtrx.de/od/tex/sfmath.html)**: "The font metrics are not adjusted to math usage (this may result in typographically unsatisfying results)."

Comment: Thanks, Werner. I was hoping that there is a method *with* lmodern...

Comment: By the way, it's still wrong if you put in $\hat{A}$ [the hat is not perfectly placed]

Comment: That's true, and that's perhaps why messages like "The functionality of this package is limited by the intention to work without additionally defined (virtual) fonts; instead, only standard fonts are used" are also given. If you're interested in manipulating the accents, use the [`accents` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/accents).

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other solution to get sans serif math fonts? As far as I know, `sfmath` is the best approach. But I won't start fixing accents since that's not the only problem. `lmodern` is a must-have for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
\renewcommand{\tilde}{\mathaccent"767E }
%\renewcommand{\tilde}{\protect\mathaccentV{tilde}67E}
```

The second line is needed if you use `amsmath`.